# mobile web development question

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have an ASP.NET MVC project with several other projects, class libraries mostly. I want to create a "mobile-friendly" version of the ASP.NET MVC app that uses the WURFL library, and I just want to know if it would be a bad practice to create a separate MVC solution? Or should I have the mobile detection within the same MVC project and serve up appropriate views? I just want to keep my concerns separate from an architectural point of view. Is it bad practice to do a redirection based on device?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to create the separate solution cause:
1. You will know for sure that users use mobile devise for see this vertion
2. Sometimes autodetection not work correctly
3. Build the new solution can be faster that setup the mobile detection on old solution 
PS> Sorry for my english :)

Comment: But you would have to do some detection in either one of the projects. So if a mobile user hits either one he will have to be directed to the mobile site.

Comment: I think yes. BUT. If i come to normal site from mobile and it redirect me to mobile version - i will be surprised, cause maybe i want to see the normal version, not mobile